# How to save result from OS Process Sampler to a variable?

Tags: process, jmeter

JMeter OS Process Sampler is set up, works fine and saves result (a token as result of powershell srcipt execution) to a file.
Is it possible somehow to save result from powershell script directly into a JMeter variable instead?

What should I add for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you should be using JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) in order to extract data from Sampler's responses

If the token is the only thing that your powershell script returns you can extract it using i.e. [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter), just provide desired variable name and leave everything else empty

Demo:

[image]

If there is some other text surrounding the token - adjust the boundaries accordingly or go for [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: Yes, ended up with the same solution as most convinient. Nice demo - thank you!